# Android 9 - BluetoothAdapter startDiscovery() not finding previously found devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an Android app that is several years old, and has worked until Android 9.  My app will do a scan of local Bluetooth devices and show them on the app.  It would do this by doing a startDiscovery() on the default BluetoothAdapter, and catching all found devices by registering a BroadcastReceiver for BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.

Pre Android 9 this works fine.  I'm not sure the exact version of Android this stopped working, perhaps Android 8 was also broken.

Post Android 9, it works once.  Meaning on my first startDiscovery() I will get Bluetooth.ACTION_FOUND for all devices, but If I quit the app and do a second startDiscovery() it is not finding the devices again.  It's like Android 9 is caching the results and not giving me a way to either clear the cache or get results from the cache.  If I disable and then re-enable the Bluetooth device then it will get new scan results.

Here's what my code looks like for registering the BroadcastReceiver (this is basically the demo code Google provides):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ...

    // Don't forget to unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver.
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

startLeScan() and BluetoothLeScanner.startScan() work fine, but I can't use these functions because this app also supports non BLE devices.

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: I've the same problem using BLE, I must restart device to works.

Comment: Same problem. Have you found a solution please ?

Comment: Not yet, please upvote the question so more people see it.  Since the app mostly supports BLE devices I just do a rescan with the BLE methods which works, unfortunately classic BL devices aren't found still.